# How do I layout a UICollection inside a List View with variable height?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

**Main question:**
How can I easily setup a UI Flow Layout of fixed size items/cells so the parent container view (or Table Cell content) grows height to fit? The flow layout should therefore not scroll its own items. Currently my parent view scrolls (see the screenshots). What is the correct constraints setup for the height of the parent view to the UICollectionView (with flow layout). What is needed in the code to allow the height of the parent view to match its child items height?

**Details:**
I am trying to create an CollectionView inside a TableCell (or any parent content view) so that:
- Parent view or table cell's height will resize to the content of the CollectionView
- The CollectionView uses Flowlayout with multiple fixed size items (i.e. 50x50) that wrap (and therefore grow the height.

Currently, the content of the flowlayout does wrap however I the parent content view always scrolls. I would like the parent view, or TableCell with a content view to automatically size to the CollectionView height. For example - one TableCell may have 3 rows of rectangles 50x50 and the parent view height would be 150. Another row may have 1 row and parent view height be 50.

[Main List Screen (Table View with Collection List in each row - items can be scrolled but the table cell doesn't resize height to fit them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNZ8t.png)

[storyboard setup for main list screen of items in table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njnlB.png)

[Example of My Awards of flowlayout items in a parent content view which doesn't fit the child items height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NopH5.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: just count the number of items you need to dispaly in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath, then do this, NSInteger maxItemPerRow = collectionView.frame.size.width/50; if number of items in datasourse is > maxItemPerRow, add another +50 to height that you return to the delegate method. there's a simple mathematical way to do this you'll have to flesh out, but this should do it. you count how many multiples of maxItemPerRow your data needs and then adjust the size according, this checfk hapens after each relaod of the colelction view

Comment: Thanks @Loxx - I was wondering if there was an automatic way to do this via storyboard or table cell auto height... i.e. even for very simple parent view to resize it's height automatically to the height of children, without manually calculating the height at runtime?

Comment: maybe so, but this is precisely why i, and most big developer shops and bigger app developers, will never touch storyboards

Comment: Got it - thanks @Loxx